# Generate sales fact data from a date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic, dimensional-modeling

I have a "placements" table with the following fields:

```
id,
name (string),
start_date (date),
end_date (date),
hourly_rate (float)
```

My goal is to run reports to see billing forecasts based on this placement data, where 8 hours are billed each workday (M-F.) The billing forecasts need to be able to be run weekly or monthly.

For example, a new placement is made for Jan 1st 2021 to Jan 31st 2021 with a hourly_rate of $50 and I am now able to run a report for an arbitrary time period (weekly, monthy, daily) and see the additional billings for that time period.

To do this, I wanted to use the placement data above to generate another set of data in a fact table that would look like this:

```
id,
placement_id,
date (date) -- or could be a reference to a date dimension table
amount (float) -- placement.hourly_rate x 8 hours
```

Is there a way to use Postgres to generate these new rows, or is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate_series()` and a lateral join:

```
select p.id, d.date, p.hourly_rate * 8 as amount
from placements p
cross join lateral generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day') d(date)
```